# How can I supress the checkstyle message "Utility classes should not have a public of default constructor" when using Spring

Tags: java, spring

In a Spring Java project I have the following class:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"PMD", "Checkstyle"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ToolBoxApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToolBoxApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Building using Jenkins tells me that I should not have a public or default constructor in a utility class.

In my checkstyle.xml withing Treewalker file I have

```
<!-- Make the @SuppressWarnings annotations available to Checkstyle -->
<module name="SuppressWarningsHolder" />
```

And the module

I tried to supress the specific check using

@SuppressWarnings({"PMD", "checkstyle:HideUtilityClassConstructor"})

but this did not work either.
The "PMD" supression does work (it effectively reports the same error).

Comment: try this `@SuppressWarnings({"PMD", "checkstyle:hideutilityclassconstructor"})`

Comment: Thank you pvpkiran, that solved it.

Comment: I will add it as an answer

Comment: Upvoted but my reputation is not high enough to be visible.

Comment: Yes, accepted. Sorry new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify checkstyle name in lower case when supressing. This will do

```
@SuppressWarnings({"PMD", "checkstyle:hideutilityclassconstructor"})
```

Answer (score 2):

We have multiple spring boot applications, so instead of adding multiple
`@SuppressWarnings` annotations, we configured a checkstyle suppression filter and added the following supression:

```
<!-- Spring Boot Application files get detected as utility classes and checkstyle wants them to have a private constructor, but a constructor is required to run the application. By convention application classes end with *Application -->
<suppress checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" files=".*Application.java"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a dummy method to avoid that rule too:

```
public void foo() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled gracefully for the specific class. As this class is needed by the SpringBoot to launch the application so it won't have any other methods  which makes it looks like a Utility Class.

Add below line in the **suppressions.xml** in your **config/checkstyle** folder. As you are excluding it only for specific file, its a good solution

```
 <suppress files="ToolBoxApplication.java"  checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" />
```

If you dont have the suppressions.xml file then rather create one. It looks like below. (Ideally shouldn't have many suppressions)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocMethod"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocPackage"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocVariable"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="MissingJavadocMethod"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocPackage"/>
    <suppress files="ConversionProxyApplication.java"  checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" />
</suppressions>
```